How to Add a Custom Module to the Webform module Dropdown in Vtiger CRM?
I'm using Vtiger CRM and have created a custom module. However, this module does not appear in the webform dropdown when configuring webforms. I'm trying to get this custom module to show up in the dropdown list. (https://i.sstatic.net/md63ZTQD.png)
How can I ensure that my custom module appears in the webform dropdown? Are there additional settings or configurations I need to adjust?
Any guidance on how to troubleshoot or additional steps to make the custom module appear in the webform dropdown would be greatly appreciated.

It's too simple

Edit Module.php in the following path
modules/Settings/Webforms/models/Module.php

Serach for $webformModules variable
$webformModules = array('Contacts', 'Accounts', 'Leads', 'Potentials', 'HelpDesk', 'Vendors');


Add your custom module in array
$webformModules = array('Contacts', 'Accounts', 'Leads', 'Potentials', 'HelpDesk', 'Vendors', 'YourCustomModule');



